# is it possible to change immersive reader’s text-to-speech maximum reading speed?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, text-to-speech

Okay, so I know you can do this on a Mac, but I'd like to change the default maximum that immersive reader can speak. Is there a way to do this? FWIW, [immersive reader](https://www.onenote.com/learningtools) is a windows text to speech program. You can test it out using OneNote and then hitting “View > Immersive Reader.”

It seems there should be since the narrator is capable of going much faster than 2.5x speed. I'd imagine that they're using a SAPI voice or something?

I do not want recommendations on how to move the slider, I already know it can go to 2.5x speed and I don't particularly care how on should go about doing this.